# How can i declare a variable in PL/SQL? Query is not working

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

It may be a simple question, but I've been researching and I can't do this. I want to insert the values ​​of the variable **"my_variable"** in the table **"endoso"**, but I don't know what the problem is, maybe it is because of the declaration of the variable but I'm not sure.
I am not an expert in SQL, any recommendation is appreciated.

```
BEGIN
declare my_variable int4;
select count(*)
from documento d 
inner join remesa r 
on r.id = d.remesa_id
where r.id=2;
insert into endoso (endoso,endosos_por_dia)
values(my_variable,2);
END
```

Comment: Hi, please indicate the DB engine.

Comment: @MattE excuse me , i'm using Oracle.

Comment: It is indeed a simple question: there is no data type `int4` in PL/SQL (which is what you are using; you are **not** using SQL).

Comment: Obviously though, you have much bigger problems than that. You have a `SELECT` statement in the middle of a PL/SQL block. In PL/SQL, you must select the value **into** something, which you are not doing. It would be better if you would explain what you were trying to do, so we can help you do what you need. It is very likely that you don't actually need to use PL/SQL - you can do everything in plain SQL.

Comment: I want to get the number of documents and insert them in endorsement (endorso, 2)

Comment: "*want to get the number of documents and insert them in endorsement*" - regardless of the DBMS you are really using: you don't need procedural code for that. You can do that with a single INSERT statement

Answer (score 3):

If the purpose of your exercise is that you take some scalar from a table, put it into a [PL/SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/toc.htm) variable and then insert that into some other table, and assuming your query is functionally correct, then this will work.

```
DECLARE
   my_variable number;  -- int4 is not an Oracle PL/SQL native type
BEGIN
   select count(*)
     into my_variable
     from documento d 
          inner join remesa r on r.id = d.remesa_id
    where r.id=2;

   insert into endoso
      (endoso, endosos_por_dia)
   values
      (my_variable, 2);

END;
```

I should mention too, that the tool that you are using to execute this code could vary quite a bit (including compiled languages such as Java). If, for example, you are using `SQL*Plus`, then you need to know that it requires something extra to know when the end of the PL/SQL block has been reached and it can then execute the code. To do that, you enter the `/` on a line by itself. But the `/` is not part of the PL/SQL block and will not be sent to and parsed by the RDBMS process for your session.

By the way, a judicious use of whitespace makes for greater readability and understanding. Style counts too but I'm not necessarily advocating for what I did.

Comment: Im using Dbeaver with a postgresql connection , i don't know if should be working with your code , but it's giving me sintax errors. Sorry @Jeff Holt

Comment: Make that your next question: "how do I execute this using that?". My recommendation is get SQL*Plus running with a username and instance that the connector would use. Execute this code. If it works, then the problem is the interface with the connector. Learn about its quirks and constraints.

Answer (score 0):

"not working" is totally devoid of actionable information.  In addition to the code corrections presented by OldProgrammer (notice the changes in DECLARE and BEGIN that he made) you also need to follow your PL/SQL block with a '/' to indicate to actually *execute* it:

```
declare
 my_variable number;
begin
    select count(*)
    into my_variable
    from documento d 
       inner join remesa r 
       on r.id = d.remesa_id
       where r.id=2;

     insert into endoso (endoso,
                         endosos_por_dia)
          values(my_variable,
                 2);

END;
/             <<--- fwd slash tells slqplus to execute the anonymous block.
```

Comment: i have postgree database not oracle like i said. I don't know if this should be working , but it's giving me sintax error. Maybe im mixing everything

Comment: Each database has its own implementation of SQL, and -- more importantly to your issue -- its own _propriatary_ procedural language.  Of course PL/SQL is not going to work on a non-oracle database.  You need to start an _all new_ question, stating the correct database.  But before you do that you need to consult the proper docs for the database you _are_ using, and work out your solution using the appropriate language.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/